# setting and retrieving external cookies through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sending an Ajax request to a PHP script where I am using `setcookie` to set the cookies on an external domain. After that, I am sending another Ajax request to the external domain to read the cookies. I am unable to achieve the results. I am using jQuery to send Ajax requests.

The PHP script:

```
<?php
// yummy cookies ?

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");

if($_GET['read'] == true) {
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'user_id' => $_COOKIE['user_id'],
            'twitter_name' => $_COOKIE['twitter_name'],
            'facebook_id' => $_COOKIE['facebook_id']
        )
    );
}

if($_GET['write'] == true) {
    if($_GET['type'] == 'twitter') {
        setcookie('twitter_name', $_GET['twitter_name'], time() + 1209600);
        setcookie('user_id', $_GET['user_id'], time() + 1209600);
    }

    if($_GET['type'] == 'facebook') {
        setcookie('facebook_id', $_GET['facebook_id'], time() + 1209600);
        setcookie('user_id', $_GET['user_id'], time() + 1209600);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into the problem where ajax doesn't allow cross site calls (can't call to another domain).

Most people use an iframe instead of ajax, put the src to the other site's cookie script.

The iframe would look like `<iframe src="otherdomain.com/cookiecode.php?var1=something" style="visibility:hidden;display:none"></iframe>`

Comment: Can you elaborate the iframe process please? :)

Comment: Simple really, just build an iframe that would display a blank page (hidden in your page) from the site you want to store the cookies (even pass variables in the url).  The iframe is loaded, storing cookies from the other domain, I'll add an example in the post.